# Angular Material Navbar not changing views

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I am new to angularjs routing. The ng-view does load the default page Home.html. But it does not change views when going to a different page. I have looked at many solutions and none of them seem to work. I am using ASP .Net Core. All of my Html files are in the wwwroot folder. The javascript files are in sub folders. Here is my html

```
<md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem"
                nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
        <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/" name="home">Home</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="#/about" name="about">About</md-nav-item>
        <md-nav-item md-nav-sref="#/contact" name="contact">
            Contact
        </md-nav-item>

    </md-nav-bar>
    <div class="ext-content">
        External content for `<span>{{currentNavItem}}</span>`.
    </div>

    <md-checkbox ng-model="disableInkBar">Disable Ink Bar</md-checkbox>

</md-content>
```

```
<div ng-view></div>'
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var portfolioApp = angular.module('portfolioApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);

portfolioApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/",
        {
            templateUrl: "/Home.html",
            controller: "NavigationController"
        })
        .when("/about",
        {
            templateUrl: "/About.html",
            controller: "NavigationController"
        })
        .when("/contact",
        {
            templateUrl: "/Contact.html",
            controller: "NavigationController"
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `md-nav-href` instead of `md-nav-sref`.

**Why?**

The [`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) directive is used as part of [`ui-router`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/). You are using the [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) module which does not support the [`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) directive.

From the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdNavItem) for `mdNavSref`:

> Ui-router state to transition to when this link is clicked. Renders as
>   a ui-sref.

From the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdNavItem) for `mdNavHref`:

> url to transition to when this link is clicked. Renders as an ng-href
>   a ui-sref.

You require the latter of the two.

Here is a working example:

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('portfolioApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute'])

})();

(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('portfolioApp').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
    
    // or use the HTML5 History API
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); // this will remove the hashbang altogether

    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        template: "Homepage {{HomeCtrl.location}}",
        controller: function() {},
        controllerAs: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
      .when("/about", {
        template: "About page",
        controller: function() {}
      })
      .when("/contact", {
        template: "Contact page",
        controller: function() {}
      });
  });

})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">

<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>


<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="portfolioApp">

  <md-content class="md-padding">

    <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
      <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/" name="home">Home</md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/about" name="about">About</md-nav-item>
      <md-nav-item md-nav-href="#/contact" name="contact">
        Contact
      </md-nav-item>
    </md-nav-bar>

    <br>

    <div class="ext-content">
      <span>Current nav item: {{currentNavItem}}</span>
    </div>

    <div ng-view class="md-padding"></div>

  </md-content>

</div>
```

Comment: I just changed the links to use md-nav-href. Im still getting the same issue.   Now when I try to navigate to another page it adds #%2F and the href name at the end of the url.

Comment: @JeremyParris Due to [aa077e8](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8), the default hash-prefix used for $location hash-bang URLs has changed from the empty string ('') to the bang ('!').  Use `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')` in your config.

Comment: Thank you I finally fixed it. I did what you suggested. I had to add $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); in my app.config and take the pound sign away in my herfs. Then the problem went away.

Comment: @JeremyParris Your welcome :) feel free to mark my answer as accepted if you feel it solved your problem.